# Mountain Duck with two factor authentication or VPN

Tags: server.app, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I am connecting to a server in Sweden from the US. I have no problem connecting to the server in Terminal using two factor authentication, required by the server in Sweden.

However, I've been struggling getting Mountain Duck to work as in addition to the password. The server in Sweden also requires the two factor authentication where I get a code on my mobile app.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide some context to “Mountain Duck?”  It appears from your question, everything on the Mac side of things is working and this may be A Mountain Duck issue.